# Send first line of the HTTP Header

Tags: curl, http

A normal HTTP request may look something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

I would like to change the first line of this request, with a custom one, e.g.:

```
FOOBAR NOT REALLY HTTP
Host: example.com
```

Is it possible to do this using `curl` or this there another tool, capable of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using tool `netcat`(also called as `nc`).

Just from command line, do the following steps to send the modified request.

```
$ nc <ip-address-of-webserver> 80
  FOOBAR NOT REALLY HTTP
  Host: example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

curl is only able to speak a couple of well defined protocols.
What you are trying to do is no valid http nor any valid other protocol.

If you *really* want to do it this way you can simply send your text for example using netcat.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options: `telnet example.com 80` and `nc example.com 80`